# Flashlight not working in nexus 5 android 6.0.1

Tags: android, nexus-5

I am new in android . i implemented code for flashlight on and off while ringing call .so this code work for every device but in nexus 5 its not working .i debug and try to find out issue but nothing do (no force close, no flash on-off).

```
Camera.Parameters pon;
Camera cam;

pon = cam.getParameters();
pon.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
```

control goes up to abov line but still its not working please help me how to fix this issue

target version is 22
compile with 22

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html

Comment: have u find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to config your `build.gradle` to work with Android 6.0 --> API 23

`build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```